# Visual Studio "Open a solution, folder, or other item"

Tags: visual-studio, repository, solution

As of recently, (probably as of Visual Studio 2022?) when I launch Visual Studio and use the "open repository" drop-down list at the bottom-right corner of the screen, Visual Studio does not just open the solution in that repository; instead, it shows me the following:

[image]

It says "Solution Explorer - Views", "Open a solution, folder, or other item", and offers the option of opening either some bizarre new kind of "Folder View", or my actual solution file.

On the toolbar of "Solution Explorer - Views" there are 3 buttons:

- A home button, which, when clicked, does nothing.
- Another icon button whose tooltip says "Switch between solutions and available views", which, when clicked, proceeds to... ***do absolutely nothing***.
- A refresh button, which, when clicked, causes the view to blink, as it presumably refreshes and just shows the exact same things.

So, I am currently resigned to either:

- Avoiding the "switch repository" menu, and using the File -> Recent Projects and Solutions menu instead, or:
- Always going through this entirely useless (to me) prompt, and having to do one more extra point-and-click on my solution file to actually open my solution.

The question is:

How can I make it ***never again*** show me this prompt and ***always proceed*** to open the solution?

I have: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.1.13.

**<rant>**

(ignore if you do not like rants)

This appears to be a recurring pattern:

1. Visual Studio introduces a new badly implemented and useless brand new feature.
2. The developers of Visual Studio are so proud of this brand new feature, that they put it right in your face, trying to change the way you work, and force you to deal with it.
3. So, naturally, the first thing you tend to want to do is to completely disable this brand new feature.
4. Of course, they never offer an option to "buzz off and continue working exactly as before", so you have to go around asking for help.
5. And here we are, on stackoverflow.

**</rant>**

**<more-rant>**

In any case, what seems to be completely useless is the entire "select repository" feature, because each time I make use of it, (and after that entirely superfluous point-and-click,) Visual Studio hits me again with that other decades-old, extremely annoying gotcha which says "A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly, bla bla bla..." Which means that when making use of the "select repository" feature, Visual Studio forgets what the startup project of the solution was.

**</more-rant>**

Comment: I also get this using vs2022. I dont know how to open the solution I really intended to open. I think it only occurs if I already have an instance of vs with another solution.